# Error Qt or wkhtmltopdf

Tags: node.js, qt, sails.js, wkhtmltopdf

When i generate a PDF with wkhtmltopdf and Qt version 4.8.6, get the following error:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/eduardo/saip/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:79:17)
    at Socket.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

I don't know what happens, also use sails v0.12.3 with node v5.10.1
How i can update upgrade my Qt?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you invoking `wkhtmltopdf`? What makes you think you need to upgrade Qt?

Comment: I am using sails.js (framework) and node.js, i've installed the npm package wkhtmltopdf. I think that need upgrade Qt after reading this: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2124, thank you.

Comment: Good find on the issue. But, that means that your question is really only about how to upgrade Qt, and that's OS specific. To upgrade Qt you'll also need administrative rights to your server.

Comment: Sorry, would two questions: 1.- How i can resolve the error displayed? and 2.- How i can update upgrade my Qt? In this forum: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2124, says i upgrade to Qt5. Thanks.

Comment: You should edit and reword your question. Perhaps something like: Is it possible to resolve this error without upgrading Qt? I don't know the answer to that question. Also for someone to be able to give advice on how to upgrade Qt we'd need to know what your operating system/package manager is. That I might be able to help with. From your system path it looks like you're on a Linux or Unix that isn't OSX.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and my OS is debian 8

Answer (score 0):

For the use of wkhtmltopdf v0.12.3, apt-get install libkdewebkit5 on debian 8.
Thanks for your help.